# Class not found exception for ini4j library

Tags: java, classpath, ini4j

I am developing a plug-in in Eclipse RCP and I have to read and write in some ini files. For that I am trying to use the ini4j library which I downloaded and added the jars as external jars in the Build Path for the project.

But when I launch the project and try to read the files I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/ini4j/InvalidFileFormatException
    at com.mbtech.tools.dioaction.ui.commands.WriteConfigFileHandler.writeFiles(WriteConfigFileHandler.java:87)
    at com.mbtech.tools.dioaction.ui.commands.TransformHandler.execute(TransformHandler.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:476)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:508)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerService.executeCommand(HandlerService.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SlaveHandlerService.executeCommand(SlaveHandlerService.java:241)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.handleWidgetSelection(CommandContributionItem.java:829)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem.access$19(CommandContributionItem.java:815)
    at org.eclipse.ui.menus.CommandContributionItem$5.handleEvent(CommandContributionItem.java:805)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4165)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3754)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2696)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2660)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2494)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:674)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at com.mbtech.tools.dioaction.ui.Application.start(Application.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ini4j.InvalidFileFormatException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:417)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(Unknown Source)
    ... 35 more
```

I googled for a solution and apparently I should also update the classpath of the project for it to work. But I am launching my project as an Eclipse Application and there is no Classpath tab when I go into the Run Configurations window.

What can I do for it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plugin.xml editor has a Runtime-Tab - there you will find a possibility to add entries to your plugin-classpath.
Add the jar and you should be set to go..